# Total number of Concurrent Proximity Alerts Active on Android

Tags: android

Does anyone know how many concurrent proximity alerts can be active on Android at a time?

Used the following API to add a proximity alert

public void addProximityAlert (double latitude, double longitude, float radius, long expiration, PendingIntent intent)

In fact , i am adding multiple geofences by fetching from the Server side. But i need to know how many geofences can be active on the device concurrently. is there any such number?>.. i think Apple iOS has something like 10 concurrent geofences active at a time ...if i am not wrong.

But is there something similar for Android?...could not gather that data anywhere in the documentation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also, it looks like there is a limit of 50 notifications that can be sent out at a time in Android.